# Increasing vertical space space between an $$ equation and text (An abnormal case)

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

In an overleaf document using `\documentclass[a4paper,15pt]{scrartcl}`, I wrote some text and thereafter, I wrote something like `$$ c^2=a^2+(-b)^2=a^2+b^2 $$` (Not this equation, please see the attached code below) followed by a new paragraph. But, the problem is that **the equation seems to be sandwiched between the two texts**. Here's the code :

```
...where $\mathbf{R_2}\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ as $\mathbf{R_2}$ is a zero matrix. So, now we have

$$\bnorm{\mathbf{R}\vec{x}-\mathbf{Q}'\vec{b}}^2~=~\bnorm{\mathbf{R_1}\vec{x}-\mathbf{c_1}}^2~+~\bnorm{-\mathbf{c_2}}^2~=~\bnorm{\mathbf{R_1}\vec{x}-\mathbf{c_1}}^2~+~\bnorm{\mathbf{c_2}}^2$$

Now, if $\mathbf{A}$ is of full column rank, then its QR decomposition is unique, hence $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ (And thus, $\mathbf{R_1}$ are fixed.
```

---

But, in some previous portions of the document, I've written things like below and in this case, **the spacing seem perfectly fine to me**. See below :

```
...The proof is following : $$\norm{\mathbf{G}\vec{x}}~=\sqrt{\left(\mathbf{G}\vec{x}\right)'\cdot\mathbf{G}\vec{x}}~=\sqrt{\vec{x}'\big(\mathbf{G}'\mathbf{G}\big)\vec{x}}=\sqrt{\vec{x}'\vec{x}}~=\norm{\vec{x}}$$

$\bullet~~\textbf{\colorbox{magicmint}{Fact \#3} :}~$ If the matrix $A$ is of full column rank, then it has a unique QR Decomposition.
```

---

Here, previously I've written

```
\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand\bnorm[1]{\big\lVert#1\big\rVert}
```

I tried using `\begin{equation*}`, but it's producing the same output. :(

Can anyone please help ? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Don't use $$ for display math, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to. Beside this: if you want help you will have to show a small complete example. Screenshots are not enough.

Comment: it is impossible to tell  without an example but note that the space around displays can stretch or shrink. If you are using a document class that uses `\flushbottom` this vertical space can change to ensure equal page lengths just as inter-word space changes on a line to maintain equal line lengths

Comment: Ohk fine. Let me write some code snippets.

Comment: code snippets are not "a small *complete* example". But don't use empty lines around display math. This math belongs to the paragraph.

Comment: Okay... but in both the cases, I've written the codes in the exact similar manner. But why are the vertical spacings are different for the two cases ?

Comment: Your code contains an empty line, which generates a paragraph break, before the first instance of `$$...$$` but not before the second. The iron rule of TeX and LaTeX says: never, ever, permit a paragraph break before starting a display-math group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You claim,

> in both the cases, I've written the codes in the exact similar manner. But why are the vertical spacings different for the two cases?

In fact, there is a *crucial difference* between the ways you wrote the two instances of `$$...$$`: In the former there's a blank line right before `$$...$$`, whereas in the latter there's not.

Blank lines in TeX and LaTeX documents trigger a paragraph break. There is an Iron Rule in TeX and LaTeX: *Never, ever* place a paragraph break immediately before a displaymath entity -- be this `$$...$$`, `\[...\]`, `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`, or what have you. Taking out the blank line immediately improves the spacing situation.

An MWE (minimum working example) that's based on your code fragment:

[image]

For the second case, I also removed all the `~` spacers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,15pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{With the spurious blank line}

\dots where $\mathbf{R}_2\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ as 
$\mathbf{R}_2$ is a zero matrix. So, now we have

\[
\norm{\mathbf{R}\vec{x}-\mathbf{Q}'\vec{b}}^2~
=~\norm{\mathbf{R}_1\vec{x}-\mathbf{c}_1}^2~+~\norm{-\mathbf{c}_2}^2~
=~\norm{\mathbf{R}_1\vec{x}-\mathbf{c}_1}^2~+~\norm{\mathbf{c}_2}^2
\]

\subsubsection*{Without the spurious blank line}

\dots where $\mathbf{R}_2\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ as 
$\mathbf{R}_2$ is a zero matrix. So, now we have
\[
\norm{\mathbf{R}\vec{x}-\mathbf{Q}'\vec{b}}^2
=\norm{\mathbf{R}_1\vec{x}-\mathbf{c}_1}^2+\norm{-\mathbf{c}_2}^2
=\norm{\mathbf{R}_1\vec{x}-\mathbf{c}_1}^2+\norm{\mathbf{c}_2}^2
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. :)